# Cakephp: mpdf stores generated pdf in forbidden directory

Tags: php, pdf, cakephp, mpdf, phpoffice

In my `Cakephp 3.6` application I am using `mpdf` to create pdf files. While on localhost is working without any problem, when I try it on the server I get this error :

> SplFileInfo::isFile() [https://secure.php.net/splfileinfo.isfile'>splfileinfo.isfile]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/tmp/mysql.sock) is not within the allowed path(s):

Thats because it is trying to save the pdf file under `src` folder and not under `webroot`.

Here is the code: (excel generator works fine)

```
$inv = TableRegistry::get('invoices')->get($invoice->id);   
$inv->file_id = $newFile->id;
TableRegistry::get('invoices')->save($inv);
$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
$writer->save($folder->path.'/timologio'.$inv->invoice_no.'.xlsx');



//Save as Pdf, even though $folder->path is pointing under webroot, its trying to save it under src
$PdfWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Mpdf');
$PdfWriter->save($folder->path.'/timologio'.$inv->invoice_no.'.pdf');
```

If I change `open_basedir` from `{WEBSPACEROOT}{/}{:}{TMP}{/}` to `none` then it is working but is it safe to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set temporary directory for PHPSpreadsheet PDF writer to a location you have access to:

```
$PdfWriter->setTempDir('path/to/your/temp/directory');
$PdfWriter->save($folder->path.'/timologio'.$inv->invoice_no.'.pdf');
```

As hinted at https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/issues/1123#issuecomment-523361110

Answer (score 0):

Setting `open_basedir` to `none` is not a good idea. A better option is to add your specific storage directory to `open_basedir`. You can do it globally in ini file, or per directory in apache config (assuming you are using apache):

`<Directory /var/www/example.domain>
  php_admin_value open_basedir /your/dir/here/:/another/dir/here
</Directory>`

Also, `src` folder is for your app source files, and I would not recommend to store generated pdfs there. Instead, I would make additional directory, for the sake of example lets name it `storage`, directly in your app directory. This way your app src will be separate from generated files.